# POST method returning empty, it has name and id

Tags: php, html, post

I am doing a login PHP code but the post method is returning empty string.

This is my HTML:

```
  <form  action="iniSesion.php" method="post" >
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="email" name="email_" 
         class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="password" name="password_" 
         class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Ingresar</button>
 </form>
```

And this is my php

```
<?php

include_once('../_includes/dbconnect.php');
$conexion  = Conexion::conectar();

$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion,$_POST["email_"]);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion,$_POST["password_"]);


print_r($_POST);
echo $_POST["email_"];
echo $_POST["password_"];

Conexion::desconectar($conexion);
?>
```

But all the echos are empty, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

------EDIT

I fount that the problem is the mysqli_real_escape_string function, but i want to use it and I don't know why it is making my POST variables empty

Comment: What is the output of `print_r($_POST)`?

Comment: Are you sure the `echo`s are empty rather than not executing? Does your error log report anything? Are you sure the script itself is being called?

Comment: it is Array ( ) @Nima

Comment: @KenY-N yes they are empty becase i have also concatened strings and they are working but when it is the variable it is empty. Like: echo 'SELECT *
 FROM usuario u
 WHERE u.usu_usuario="' .$_POST["email_"] . '" and u.usu_password="'.$_POST["password_"].'"';

Comment: Are you sure its not something failing *before* posting the data?

Comment: @Unknown I dont know what can it be? How can i check that

Comment: The ideal way would be to debug it. If you can't debug it, then comment out lines before displaying the data.

Comment: @Unknown yes I tried commenting everything and only doing an echo but nothing

Comment: Hmm, maybe check spelling and see if you missed a letter? Maybe you missed an 's' in 'iniSesion.php'?

Comment: @Unknown I found the error, the mysqli_real_escape_string is not working, if I only do the POST alone it works. What is the problem with that function??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9055974/mysqli-real-escape-string-not-working-correctly Take a look there..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155286/discussion-between-mariana-hernandez-and-unknown).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mysqli_real_escape_string()
```

^ This requires an active connection to the database before it can be used.

This code will have to go before `mysqli_real_escape_string()` :

```
$DatabaseConnection = mysqli_connect
```